# Difference between coding of dictionaries in python versions

Tags: python

I have following codestrings:

```
#coding: utf
import json
import base64
from lxml import html, etree
import urllib2

somedictionary={}
url1="someurl1"
base64string = base64.b64encode('%s:%s' % ('user', 'pass'))
xml1request = urllib2.Request(url1)
xml1request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
xml1=etree.parse(urllib2.urlopen(xml1request))
somelist=xml1.xpath("//list1//a/text()")

for element in somelist:
    url2="part of url2"+element+"part of url2"
    xml2request=urllib2.Request(url2)
    xml2request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
    xml2=etree.parse(urllib2.urlopen(xml2request))

    b=xml2.xpath("//list2//b/text()") 
    c=xml2.xpath("//list2//c/text()")
    d=xml2.xpath("//list2//d/text()")
    e=xml2.xpath("//list2//e/text()")
    somedictionary[key.index(element)]={key.index(element):{"a": element, "b": b, "c": c, "d": d, "e": e}}
    #json.dump(bamboo, open("12345.txt","w"))
```

in python 3.4.0 it works.
But in python 2.7.10 it returns me an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\11.py", line 25, in <module>
    somedictionary[key.index(element)]={key.index(element):{"a": a, "b": b, "c": c, "d": d, "e": e}}
NameError: name 'key' is not defined
>>>
```

Variables `b`,`c`,`d`,`e` announced in cycle;
`somedictionary` announced before cycle
I don't found some information about this moment in pythondocks
How to fix it, if it works in python 3.4.0?

Comment: If you get `NameError: name 'key' is not defined` then you most likely forgot to define it in python2

Comment: in this context, "key" like in pair (key,value)

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you posted, it's in the code that's supposed to set `key`. You need to post that code.

Comment: As per my first comment, it is not defined anywhere, the code as it stands would not run in any Python version.

Comment: but it works in python 3.4

Comment: @lwwwr, it 100 percent does not work as posted.

Comment: i changed url's on some text in this code. in my version with true url's it works, in good faith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way it could work in python3 and not python2 is if *somelist* is empty in python3 so you never reach the code inside the loop:

```
In [20]: l = []

In [21]: for ele in l: 
           print(not_defined) # never reach here 
   ....:     

In [22]: l = [1]

In [23]: for ele in l:
           print(not_defined) # loop once so we get here and error
   ....:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-6e24b65bf7e0> in <module>()
      1 for ele in l:
----> 2            print(not_defined)
      3 

NameError: name 'not_defined' is not defined
```

You never defined  the name *key* anywhere so bar *somelist* is empty you would get a *NameError* as above in  both *python2* and *python3*.

So you have two problems, in *python3* your code is not finding anything, if it did you still have the *key* issue as you don't define it anywhere so you need to figure out what *key* should be and debug your *python3* logic.